# Money Drinking Hippo? What is a 돈먹는하마?

Tags: etymology, word-origin, phrase-meaning

On Twitter, #돈먹는하마 is trending.  I know they are talking about post-olympic stadiums costing a lot of money.  What is this use of "`hippo/하마`" in this phrase?

[image]

---

### What is this use of "`hippo/하마`" in this phrase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a word play on 물먹는 하마, a very famous brand of moisture absorber (see picture).

*[So the word play is that like this "water eating hippo" product absorbs water, the olympic stadiums in a post-olympic country absorb monetary resources.]*

[image: 물먹는하마]

Comment: Can you use this in any other context? Is this a common phrase, or something this one person just made up to make a point?

Comment: The expression is relatively common in news. https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=%EB%A8%B9%EB%8A%94+%ED%95%98%EB%A7%88 : I can see "돈먹는 하마", "세금 먹는 하마", "전기 먹는 하마", "혈세를 잡아먹는 하마", and so on.

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful. __먹는 하마 seems to be the pattern.